# How do I assign groups of meshes to randomly go into collections?

Tags: export

[image: Trying to create a bookcase with books that have a mix of]
I have constructed a mesh 'bookcase' with many books on many levels. My ultimate aim is to export the bookcase and all books as a single mesh. However, I would like to ensure that my book spines have a healthy amount of color variation (as pictured).

Inside blender this is easy. I ensure that the material has an Object node (Random Object plug) that drives a color-ramp that chooses from appropriate options along the ramp.

But this is ultimately for OBJ export. So I just need standard PBR materials with no tricks.

I would like to take all the little book meshes and divide them into groups. Then I would make a single material for each collection of random books and join them into a single mesh.

I hope this makes sense. I would love to speed the creation of these assets and am sure there is some selection magic that can do it, but I have yet to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Follow-up: So far, my best strat is to hide everything and then do successive 'random selects' until I have manually broken out meshes that way. This is doable, but I'll still hold out hope for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways would be to enable proportional editing in random falloff, $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down* to increase range and move on the axis where all books originally share position (at least it seems so in your screenshot), then you can box select some books, press <kbd>M</kbd> and move them to a new collection, <kbd>H</kbd> to temporarily hide them and repeat for next groups of books. In the end you can restore the positions of books by a tool like *Object > Transform > Align objects*...

[image]

Positions could also be saved and restored by Python scripts, but then the objects could just be added to random collections by a Python script...

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from random import choice

new_cols = [D.collections.new(str(i)) for i in range(10)]
for col in new_cols:
    C.collection.children.link(col)

for ob in D.objects:
    for col in ob.users_collection:
        col.objects.unlink(ob)
    choice(new_cols).objects.link(ob)
```